# Onepage Checkout - Displaying Billing/Shipping Address (Outside Progress Sidebar)

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, php-5.4

What is the best way to display customer-entered information such as billing, shipping, and payment info into the checkout process?

The following is an example to demonstrate what I mean.

The first step is the customer has to enter their billing information:

[image: Checkout - Billing]

The customer proceeds with shipping information, shipping method, and payment information before reviewing the order:

[image: Checkout - Payment]

I would like to display previously entered information under each section where the "Edit" links are, once the customer is past each step. Is there a way to do this?

---

Some additional information:

The progress sidebar is hidden via /theme/skin/frontend/[package]/default/css/styles.css:

```
#checkout-progress-wrapper {display:none;}
```

Here is my /app/design/frontend/[package]/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('varien/accordion.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/opcheckout.js') ?>"></script>
<ol class="opc" id="checkoutSteps">
<?php $i=0; foreach($this->getSteps() as $_stepId => $_stepInfo): ?>
<?php if (!$this->getChild($_stepId) || !$this->getChild($_stepId)->isShow()): continue; endif; $i++ ?>
    <li id="opc-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="section<?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['allow'])?' allow':'' ?><?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['complete'])?' saved':'' ?>">
        <div class="step-title">
            <span class="number"><?php echo $i ?></span>
            <h2><?php echo $_stepInfo['label'] ?></h2>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
        </div>
        <div id="checkout-step-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_stepId) ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>

<input type="hidden" name="checkout_method" id="login:guest" checked="checked" value="guest"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var accordion = new Accordion('checkoutSteps', '.head', true);
    <?php if($this->getActiveStep()): ?>
    accordion.openSection('opc-billing');
    <?php endif ?>

    var checkout = new Checkout(accordion,{
        progress: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/progress') ?>',
        review: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/review') ?>',
        saveMethod: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveMethod') ?>',
        failure: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>'}
    );

    //IE fix
    var cb = $("login:guest");
    cb.checked = true;

    checkout.setMethod();
//]]>
</script>
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert of Prototype.js, but it seems like the progress sidebar is modified by the `reloadStep` function of the `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js` script.

```
reloadStep: function(prevStep) {
    var updater = new Ajax.Updater(prevStep + '-progress-opcheckout', this.progressUrl, {
        method:'get',
        onFailure:this.ajaxFailure.bind(this),
        onComplete: function(){
            this.checkout.resetPreviousSteps();
        },
        parameters:prevStep ? { prevStep:prevStep } : null
    });
},
```

Where `prevStep + '-progress-opcheckout'` (prevStep could be `billing`, `payment` etc.) determines which block has to be edited.

One solution, but clearly not the best way, would be to add the code below just after the `step-title` div.

```
<div id="<?php echo $_stepId ?>-progress-opcheckout"></div>
```

As an `id` has to be unique, you would have to disable completely the progress sidebar, so not only hiding it.

Comment: Thanks! That appears like it would work with some additional styling changes. In case anyone is having a similar problem, they can remove the progress block (instead of hiding it via CSS) by using the following code in the local.xml file: <remove name="checkout.progress.wrapper" />